# SHA-256 of large file using CryptoKit

Tags: swift, cryptography, apple-cryptokit

Does anyone know a way to calculate de SHA-256 hash of a file without having to load the entire file on memory?

I would be ideal to use apple's CryptoKit library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a hasher:

```
let hasher = SHA256()
```

With each chunk you read (in whatever way or size you want to read it), update the hasher:

```
hasher.update(data: blockOfData)
```

(or if you have an `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`, you can pass that)

And when you're done, finalize it:

```
let hash = haser.finalize()
```

Comment: I have changed the name "block" to "chunk" in above answer as hash functions have a specific block size (e.g. 512 bit for SHA-256 and 1024 bit for SHA-512). I used "chunk" to indicate a (usually much larger) piece of a file of any size.

Comment: Can anyone show me an implementation of how to actually read a file in chunks in a memory efficient way. I tried using both `FileHandle` and `InputStream` but my memory usage goes up a lot (800 mb).

Comment: You need to wrap your loop in an `autoreleasepool{}` block so it'll let go of temporary memory you allocate in the loop.

Comment: I have tried that and i cant seem to make it work. [This is the post i made about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66147377/read-a-file-by-chunks)

Comment: Nevermind, i just found out i was never executing my function and was instead executing anotherone.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `FileHandle` to read the data in chunks, and pass these into the hasher:

```swift
import CryptoKit

func getSHA256(forFile url: URL) throws -> SHA256.Digest {
    let handle = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: url)
    var hasher = SHA256()
    while autoreleasepool(invoking: {
        let nextChunk = handle.readData(ofLength: SHA256.blockByteCount)
        guard !nextChunk.isEmpty else { return false }
        hasher.update(data: nextChunk)
        return true
    }) { }
    let digest = hasher.finalize()
    return digest

    // Here's how to convert to string form
    //return digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
}
```